# Magento - make the field "company" required

Tags: magento

for a B2B Magento site, when registering a new client, I want to make the field "company" required.

Which file should I edit?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you are registering/creating customers manually or customers registering themselves? which one?

Comment: On customers registering themselves, thanks

Comment: I don't even see "company" as an optional field. Where is that configuration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should as well add it in your attribute on the server side.

If you're using Magento **Entreprise Edition**, you can simply edit the company attribute through back end, and **set it to "required"**.

If you're working with a **Community Edition**, you'll have to **manually change this value with SQL**. It's in `eav_attribute` table, the `attribute_code` is `company` and you just need to set `is_required` to `1`.

Comment: I am trying to make "telephone" not required. I changed is_required to 0 in eav_attribute. The frontend still shows the "required" asterisk. So I edit the frontend as per Oguz's answer below. Now the form POSTs, but the result of the POST is "Please enter the telephone number". What further steps should I take?

Comment: I don't have a Magento install at hand, so I can't really help, but my advice would be _not_ to change the template. You should be able to change that only through the DB. Are you sure you've chnaged the right EAV attribute? Maybe you've changed it for another entity...

Comment: I actually had to override the form controller - there is another test in there for the presence of telephone.

Comment: @RobertOnslow Hi Rober, How exactly do you override the form controller?

Answer (score 12):

Additionally to haltabush answer (which is the correct one) here is the SQL for lazy developers:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 1 WHERE attribute_code = 'company';
```

Comment: no. it is just what the enterprise edition does when you edit the attribute in the backend. But what you are doing is to fix it for the frontend but not for the backend... anyway, hacking magento is not a good idea. really.

Comment: Why was this undervote? This is one of the correct answers. If not the most completed.

Answer (score 5):

**For Customer Address Book Section (registered customers ) :**

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml

**For checkout billing section :**

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

**For checkout shipping section :**

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

**For registration section :**

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
>
> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/address.phtml

Find looks like following line for required fields :

```
class="input-text validate-email required-entry"
```

Comment: Do you know that you've set (hardcoded!) the field as required just for the frontend and not for the backend?

Comment: Besnik, it's not my problem. I just referenced where it is. If you have a serious developer you should know how it is override the function. If not, you need a simple solution. As you might guess, nobody like you, especially small site owners! Besides, I used many times and haven't seen any problem. Of course, if you don't need those fields!

Comment: Although it has a similar effect, this is definitely not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it using installer. The proper way to do it in magento. This works for enterprise edition and comunity edition. But you will have to have the module configured to understand a file under sql folder

```
<?php
    $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');;

    $installer->startSetup();


    $installer->run("UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 1 WHERE attribute_code = 'company';");


    $installer->endSetup();
```

This is how is my module xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_Customer>
            <version>1.1.0.4</version>
        </Package_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
      ....
       <resources>
        <package_customer_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Package_Customer</module>
            </setup>
        </package_customer_setup>
         </resources>
       ....
     </global>
```

This is what I did to edit.phtml to make it dynamic

```
    <li class="wide">
        <?php 
            $validation_class = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ;
            $required = strstr($validation_class, 'required-entry');
        ?>
        <label for="company" class=<?php echo $required?"required":""?>><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?> <?php echo $required?"<em>*</em>":""?> </label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $validation_class ?>" />
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

### There is a backend setting you can set (version 2.4.5-p1).

You can find it in `Stores > Settings > Configuration`, then under `Customers > Customer Configuration` you will find the option "Show Company" under the tab "Name and Address Options".

It looks like this:

[image]

Setting the option to required will make the company a required field in all address forms.