# Magento - make the field “company” required for multi-store site

Tags: magento, required-field

I have found how to set the company field as being required in this thread ([Magento - make the field "company" required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456794/magento-make-the-field-company-required)) however I want to do this for only one site in a multi-site store.  How do I do this?

In the database I don't see any reference to site, just the single record for attribute_code = 'company.

Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0):

You can specify required fields for customer for different websites in `customer_eav_attribute_website` table.